# Can I send gcm message directly from one device to another if sender app has registration id of reciever?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to know if there is any way to send push notification from one client app to another directly without app server. If for example client app A has GCM registration id of client app B then can A send push notification directly to B without web server. Please guide me on how to accomplish this task if it is possible. I did not find any article about this topic on google and also the official documentation is not pointing out this phenomenon.

Comment: `I want to know if there is any way to send push notification from one client app to another directly without app server?` No

Comment: I think it is not possible.

Comment: Actually in my project server is too busy to do this task. So i want to do it device to device directly without involving my server.

Comment: refer this http://androidexample.com/Device_To_Device_Messaging_Using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=122&aaid=142

Comment: but it involves web server.